# Delete Postmaster.pid file in postgres directory

Tags: postgresql, macos

Yesterday My MacBook (El Capitan) laptop struct due to some issue with wifi. At that time I clicked on Postgres icon on which is present in the menubar. Then I opened Activity monitor force quit the Postgres server.

Now I want to run my Postgres server it showing **postmaster.pid** should be deleted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Again now I got the solution.

simply just go to this folder

My self using postgres 10 that's why I got var-10 folder you may get another oner.

```
/Users/gunarevuri/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-10
```

then

```
cd var-10
```

then

```
rm postmaster.pid
```

it automatically deletes file.

You can run your Postgres server from the menu bar or from the app.

[image: Here below screenshot for detailed explanation]

Answer (score 2):

You should never manually delete `postmaster.pid`. It is one of the safeguards that are there to prevent you from starting two PostgreSQL servers on the same data directory, which would cause immediate data corruption.

When PostgreSQL starts, it checks for the existence of `postmaster.pid`. If the file is found, PostgreSQL reads the first line, which is a process ID. It then checks if there is a process with that ID or not.

- If there is such a process, PostgreSQL will refuse to start.
- If there is no such process, then PostgreSQL will print a warning, but it will still try to start.

Of course there is a certain possibility that the process ID in `postmaster.pid` is taken by a different process that started after the original database server crashed. Then you get a false positive error from PostgreSQL, and it won't start. In that case, you'll have to remove the file manually to start PostgreSQL, but you had better double check that it is really **not** a PostgreSQL process.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

`brew postgresql-upgrade-database`